# I Wish to Save Configuration With System IP Address

Tags: python, networking, configuration

I am new to Python and have just successfully completed writing and testing a script that will do the following:

1. Telnet into the switch.
2. Log in with credentials provided.
3. Open a file and then redirect the output of the commands to it.
4. Logout from the switch once done.

What I wish it to do:

I want my script to create a file in the specified directory using the IP address of the switch. Like configuration from switch with the IP address of 192.168.1.30 should be saved as 192.168.1.30.txt.

Below is a part of my script

============================

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pexpect
import datetime

HOST = raw_input ("Enter the IP Address Of the switch:")
user=admin
password=admin

child = pexpect.spawn ('telnet', [HOST])
child.logfile = open("/home/tester/scripts/config.txt", "w")
```

==============================

As you can see if I ran the above script, the output of the commands sent via the script will be saved to the config.txt file. The contents will be erased if a different switch is telnet'd into and contents from the new switch will be saved. So, I would like the script to use the IP address entered by the user and then save the output of the commands in a different file using the IP address as the filename, so that contents of the file do not get over-written.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `HOST` is the string `"192.168.1.30"`, and you want the file to be named `"/home/tester/scripts/192.168.1.30.txt"`, you can do this with simple string concatenation:

```
path = "/home/tester/scripts/" + HOST + ".txt"
```

… or, better, with [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
path = "/home/tester/scripts/{}.txt".format(HOST)
```

Then:

```
child.logfile = open(path, "w")
```

(Of course you can also do the concatenation or `format` right in the middle of the `open` expression, if you prefer, but I think it's more readable this way.)